# express checkout: possible values of payment_status field in ipn after pending

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I wonder what are possible values of field payment_status in ipn?
I can see in simulate in sanbox ipn with payment_status: Completed and Reverse.
Are other values possible for checkout transaction like Failed, Denied if transaction is
not completed after pending?

I implement paying using express checkout.
I process ipn to see if there are transaction with payment_status = 'Completed' if transaction had payment_status = 'Pending'.
If I cick Accept for pending transaction in checkbox, I receive ipn with payment_status = 'Completed' and implement purchase.
If I cick Deny for pending transaction in checkbox, I receive ipn with payment_status = 'Reversed' (but parent_txn_id is set to transaction not txn_id), which is rather suprising I thought it would be with payment_status Denied, I want to mark transaction denied in my system.
I wonder if I need to analyse other values to mark transaction as denied in my system.
How to analyze if payment is declined?

Answer (score 0):

Open up [PayPal's IPN Variables documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) and do a find on the page for payment_status.  Step your way down the page to see where it could come up and what values might be.

Comment: I looked at this page. But I can't find what ipn can be received after pending except Completed and Reversed I can simulate in sandbox. What values of payment_status can be for ipn if transaction is denied? I can see strange ipn with Reversed, are valued like Failed and Denied possible after pending?

Comment: I wonder what values of payment_status are possible for pending transactions except: Completed and Reversed.

Comment: Why is ipn sent with status Reversed when I click deny for pending transaction in sandboc?